# Interpreting MSBuild Performance Summary Output

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to understand some performance summary output from MSBuild.  The results look like this:

```
Target Performance Summary:
        0 ms  PrepareForRun                             74 calls
        0 ms  Compile                                   74 calls
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    15173 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                  74 calls
    29607 ms  Build                                     75 calls

Task Performance Summary:
        2 ms  CreateCSharpManifestResourceName           6 calls
        2 ms  ResolveKeySource                           1 calls
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
     3623 ms  Copy                                     511 calls
     7468 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                  74 calls
    11234 ms  Exec                                      12 calls
    48600 ms  MSBuild                                  210 calls

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:29.60
```

Why does the total time for MSBuild exceed the total elapsed time?  The actual stopwatch time to run this build was, in fact, ~29 seconds.  Any examples of these summaries that I see online show that the total Task and Target times are same.

Comment: ResolveAssemblyReferences(RAR) and ResolveCOMReferences (RCR) usually take the most time.

Comment: @RitchMelton Actually, they don't. I've added tracing to those targets (by directly modifying Microsoft targets) and they show RAR takes very little time The whole time reporting seems broken to me...

Comment: They used to. Demonstrably so. I'd be surprised if it magically changed.

Comment: Why not just do a diag?

Comment: It works the same. Saying it doesn't is just bad info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSBuild and CallTarget tasks invoke other targets (and thus other tasks). The time spent in those tasks is counted against the MSBuild and CAllTarget tasks as well. A bug, really.

So when reading this data, always ignore those two tasks. Summing the other tasks should come to a little less than the total build time.